# SQL Injection in server_processing.php

Tags: php, mysql

We had a security audit on our code, and they mentioned that our code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack.

Explanation- Below code ($rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());) of server_processing.php invokes a SQL query built using input coming from an untrusted source. This call could
allow an attacker to modify the statement's meaning or to execute arbitrary SQL commands.

```
/*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    **$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());**
```

SQL injection errors occur when:
1. Data enters a program from an untrusted source.
2. The data is used to dynamically construct a SQL query.

Example : The following code dynamically constructs and executes a SQL query that searches for items matching a specified
name. The query restricts the items displayed to those where the owner matches the user name of the currently-authenticated
user.
...

```
$userName = $_SESSION['userName'];
$itemName = $_POST['itemName'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE owner = '$userName' AND itemname = '$itemName';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

...
The query that this code intends to execute follows:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE owner = <userName>
AND itemname = <itemName>;
```

However, because the query is constructed dynamically by concatenating a constant query string and a user input string, the
query only behaves correctly if itemName does not contain a single-quote character. If an attacker with the user name wiley
enters the string "name' OR 'a'='a" for itemName, then the query becomes the following:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE owner = 'wiley'
AND itemname = 'name' OR 'a'='a';
```

The addition of the OR 'a'='a' condition causes the where clause to always evaluate to true, so the query becomes logically
equivalent to the much simpler query:

```
SELECT * FROM items;
```

This simplification of the query allows the attacker to bypass the requirement that the query only return items owned by the
authenticated user; the query now returns all entries stored in the items table, regardless of their specified owner.

SO we have sql injection in below code-

1. Filtering-

   $sWhere = "";
   if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
   {
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i$sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET    ['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
      }
   $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
   $sWhere .= ')';
    }
2. SQL queries-

   $sQuery = "
       SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
       FROM   $sTable
       $sWhere
       $sOrder
       $sLimit
   ";
   $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
3. Ordering-

   $sOrder = "";
   if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
   {
       $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
       for ( $i=0 ; $iGET[ 'bSortable'.intval($*GET['iSortCol*'.$i]) ] == "true" )
           {
               **$sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $*GET['iSortCol*'.$i] ) ]."
                   ".mysql_real_escape_string( $*GET['sSortDir*'.$i] ) .", ";**
           }
       }

   ```
   $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
   if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
   {
       $sOrder = "";
   }
   ```

   }
4. Paging-

   $sLimit = "";
          if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
            {
               $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET'iDisplayStart'] ).", ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET'iDisplayLength'] );**
            }

5-  Individual column filtering -

```
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            **$sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";**
        }
    }
```

Please help how can I remove sql injection in my code.

Can anyone help where I am missing things? Anyone help is appreciated !

Comment: This has been fairly documented here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1. Also, did you tried switching to PDO? `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated and PDO will let use prepared statements to avoid injections.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace each single quote with a double single quote.

```
$itemName = str_replace("'","''",$name);
```

This will work in a pinch if you aren't able to make any significant changes. Though the previous comment is correct. The best method would be using parameterized queries.